# Android Studio — Changing generation path and filename of both unsigned and signed APKs

Tags: android, android-studio

Are there any configuration files where I can change the default path of generated (both debug and release) APKs in Android Studio? Can I change the filename of the generated files so it includes the version or the timestamp?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure that I'm using such soultion in my code ... also I'm pretty sure that I found the solution on this site (via google.com)

Comment: I would not ask if I had found it via google.com, @Selvin.

Comment: `custom+apk+path+gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, @Selvin gave me the way to understand how to do it, but I'll post it anyway. In your `build.gradle` you have to edit your `buildTypes.release` section.

```
release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def date = new Date()
                def format = date.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                        "apk/" + output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", " - release - v" + defaultConfig.versionCode + " - (" + format + ")"))
            }
        }
    }
```

This way, the exported `release` apk will be generated in `{project folder}/apk/{project name} - release - v{versionCode} - {date and hour of compilation}.apk`